# Export HighChart 3D pie chart into png is not working

Tags: node.js, highcharts

I'm using the **highcharts-export-server** library convert high chart `JSON` into `PNG`. It is working for normal chart. But I'm getting normal pie chart even If I set the `3D` option. But It is working as expected in browser.

```
    {
  "options": {
    "plotOptions": {},
    "exporting": false,
    "credits": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "series": [
      {
        "data": [],
        "name": "Distribution by pps",
        "type": "pie",
        "colorByPoint": true
      }
    ],
    "title": {
      "text": "Distribution by pps"
    },
    "chart": {
      "options3D": {
        "alpha": 45,
        "enabled": true,
        "beta": 0
      },
      "type": "pie"
    }
  },
  "type": "png"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's happening because there is a little typo in your confiuration. You need to change `"options3D":` to `"options3d":` and then try to export your chart.

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.options3d